# merge/cbind model matrices

Tags: r, formula, model.matrix

This is a simplified version of my current problem. I need to create a model.matrix from 2 model matrices, without loosing the info in "assign". For example, consider data and formula

```
y<-rnorm(100); x1<-rnorm(100); x2<-rnorm(100); x3<-rnorm(100)
f1 <- y ~ x1 + x2 + x3
```

and 2 model matrices `X1` and `X2` created using

```
trms<-terms.formula(f1)
trms2<-drop.terms(trms, dropx = 2)
trms3<-drop.terms(trms, dropx = -2)
X1<-model.matrix(trms2)
X2<-model.matrix(trms3)
```

Is there an easy way to create from `X1` and `X2` a matrix `X` with 1 intercept column and with `attr(,"assign")` that would have been obtained from `f1`?

Comment: @李哲源 I think I did simplify the problem too much. In reality `x1` can be a matrix, `x2` a smooth construct (from mgcv: s(x2,k=10)) and `x3` another matrix. So I wanted to drop terms to process them differently, depending on what they are, and then merge them.

Comment: @李哲源 not even if the formula has factors / matrix variables?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, how about something simple and direct like:

```
X3                <- cbind(X1[,1:2], X2[,2], X1[,3])
attr(X3,"assign") <- c(0,1,2,3)
colnames(X3)      <- c("Intercept",attr(trms, "term.labels"))
head(X3)
```

> ```
>   Intercept          x1         x2         x3
> 1         1 -1.28372461 -0.2598796  0.3028496
> 2         1  0.56880875  0.2803302  0.7593734
> 3         1 -0.32480770 -1.6705911 -1.1750247
> 4         1 -1.02761734 -0.1405454 -0.6805033
> 5         1  0.84218452 -0.1224962 -1.3882420
> 6         1  0.07221231  0.5587801 -0.9042751
> ```

Comment: @papgeo Oh, thanks now I understand what you meant! Let me fix it in an edit right now. **Update:** Please see my revised answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completly sure if this is what you are trying to do but `cbind()` seems to work fine in this case.

```
X <- cbind(X1, X2)
X <- X[, !duplicated(colnames(X))]
```

You can then concatenate the attributes from X1 and X2. In order not to get duplicates you can only take the assign info from X2 which isn't already present in X1:

```
attributes(X)$assign <- c(attr(X1,"assign"), attr(X2,"assign")[!attr(X2,"assign") %in% attr(X1,"assign")])
```

If this is not what you were trying to to let us know.

Comment: Thank you. The `!duplicated` certainly helps, but `attr(,"assign")` is not what I need. It only has 0, 1, 2 (the 3 is missing, )

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this comment. What do you want instead?

Comment: `attr(X,"assign")` to show 0,1,2,3. Now it shows 0,1,2.